# Ruby on Rails web application doesn't see environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My Ruby on Rails web application doesn't see environment variable on localhost (Windows 8).

I have the following line in the `config/database.yml` file:

```
password: <%= ENV["'TECHNICAL_SUPPORT_TIMER_DEFAULT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'"] %>
```

And when I call `set` command in the cmd.exe it lists this environment variable.

I've tried to restart server, but nothing happens -- it still shows the "fe_sendauth: no password supplied" error.

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
password: <%= ENV['TECHNICAL_SUPPORT_TIMER_DEFAULT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

you have the variable wrapped in single and double quotes

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't want to explicitly mention your password and that you want to keep it secure. Try following the instructions shown in this website:
http://effectif.com/articles/database-yml-should-be-checked-in?
Hope this helps you!